# gcc7 port is later than gcc8

Tags: gcc, macports

Today, I was viewing the directory `http://jog.id.distfiles.macports.org/macports/distfiles/` and found that:

```
gcc-7.3.0.tar.xz    60M 02-Feb-2018 21:46
```

while

```
gcc-8-20170604.tar.xz   57M 04-Sep-2017 10:27
```

That is, gcc8 is outdated with respect to gcc7. How?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html#timeline would give you a feel for the thing. Also what "distributions" do with what patches is up to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC 7.3 is the second point release off the GCC 7 release branch.  It was released upstream on January 25, 2018.

`gcc-8-20170604.tar.xz` looks like a development snapshot from Subversion trunk.  The first released GCC 8 version was 8.1, on May 2, 2018.

See these resources on GCC release history:

- [GCC Releases](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html)
- [Release Timeline](https://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html#timeline)

Comment: +1) To add to advice for the OP's convenience, run `sudo port uninstall gcc8` (the 'pre-release' you currently have), and `sudo port install gcc8 [-universal]` to install the *now* available `gcc-8.2.0` stable. Note that at this time, there's a `gcc9` port - but looking at `port list | grep gcc`, you can see it's still in snapshot / development phase.

Answer (score 0):

The date of the source code tarball does not mean that a port is older than another port. For example, this may just be the date on which our mirroring script downloaded the file from upstream and placed it on distfiles.macports.org.

Whether MacPorts considers a port "newer" than another port only depends on the tuple (epoch, version, revision). However, this also does not apply to GCC, because MacPorts packages both GCC 7.x and GCC 8.x in separate ports so that they can be installed side-by-side.